# Add a function to OnLoad in Drupal

Tags: php, javascript, drupal

I have a HTML/text default module in the left bar of one of my skins/themes. I have some Javascript in there I'm trying to set today date to my javascript date dropdowns. I am unable to use 'body.onLoad' because Drupal is blocking it somehow?

I found a solution saying I can add my javascript function here:
if (isJsEnabled()) {
  addLoadEvent(yourCustomJSFunction);
}

How can I add that if I'm just using a default HTML/text module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Drupal uses the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) JavaScript library. Any JavaScript you write to work with Drupal should ideally use jQuery as well. Check out the [JavaScript Startup Guide](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--javascript_startup_guide.html/6) on api.drupal.org for some basics, particularly the [`Drupal.behaviors`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--javascript_startup_guide.html/6#Drupal.behaviors) section.

Comment: +1 - The right links for this, especially the Drupal.behaviors one.